# how do we find out the value of one through anohter

Tags: excel

Column A contains Regions And Column B contains Name of cities.

```
Regions Name Of City
East     ABC
west     XYZ
north    PQR
south    WXY
East     City-1
west     City-2
```

I want ***find which all cities lies under east, west,north, south region,***

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: You can achieve it by advance filtering. Its also possible by formula (Array formula).

Comment: Just sort the name of city column by expanding selection..

Answer (score 0):

So there are quite a few ways to differentiate between the different regions.

1) . Highlight top row, Date Tab, Filter. Probably the quickest and easiest way

2).  Conditional formating. That is on the home tab under "styles"

3).  Pivot Table.

4). Grouping function (see image) which is also super easy

[image]

Im not totally sure that this question was worth asking, but whatever I hope this helps :)